# $AD = 4\; AB = 3\; CD = 9\;$ What is the area of $\triangle AEC? $

Tags: contest-math, triangles, area

[image]
$AD = 4,\; AB = 3,\; CD = 9\;$ What is the area of $\triangle AEC? $
I cant find a way out... Any hint will be helpful...

**PS**: This is a Problem from BDMO Regional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\triangle ECD$ is similar to $\triangle EBA$, so
$$\frac{AE}{DE} = \frac{AB}{DC} = \frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Since $AE+DE=AD=4$, we have $AE=1$ and $DE=3$. From here, subtracting the area of $\triangle CED$ from $\triangle ACD$ will give you the answer.

Comment: ops... How I missed it.... Thanks..... :)